# Asp.net MVC5 angular4 Uncaught Reference Error: System is not defined in systemjs.config.js after deploying to IIS

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-7

I have created Asp.Net MVC Angular2 application which is working fine while running in visual studio2017 External Host. But when i publish this application and run through IIS. i am receiving an error as

Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined in

1. systemjs.config.js and
2. _Layout.cshtml

   System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });

Below is my Bundle.config class:

```
public class BundleConfig
{
     public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angular").Include(                
                   "~/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js",
                   "~/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js",                                 
                   "~/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js",
                   "~/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js",
                   "~/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js",
                   "~/systemjs.config.js"
                   ));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(                      
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js",                      
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"                       
                  ));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css",
                  "~/Content/font-awesome.min.css",
                  "~/Content/animate.min.css",
                  "~/node_modules/angular2-busy/build/style/busy.css",
                  "~/node_modules/ng2-toastr/bundles/ng2-toastr.min.css",
                   "~/Content/custom.css"                       
                  ));          
    }
}
```

systemjs.config.js

```
 (function (global) {
        SystemJS.config({        
        paths: {
            'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        map: {
          'app': 'app',

          '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
          '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
          '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
          '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
          '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
          '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
          '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
          '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
          '@angular/animations': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations.umd.js',
          '@angular/animations/browser': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js',
          '@angular/platform-browser/animations': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js', 
          'file-saver': 'npm:file-saver/',
          'angular2-busy': 'npm:angular2-busy',

          'ng2-smart-table': 'npm:ng2-smart-table',
          'ng2-completer': 'npm:ng2-completer',
          'ng2-bs3-modal': 'npm:/ng2-bs3-modal',
          'lodash': 'npm:lodash',
          'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
          'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
          'mydatepicker': 'npm:mydatepicker/bundles/mydatepicker.umd.min.js',
          'ng2-toastr': 'npm:ng2-toastr',

          'moment': 'npm:moment',
          'ngx-pipes': 'npm:ngx-pipes/bundles/ngx-pipes.umd.min.js'

        },
        packages: {
                app: { main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
                rxjs: { defaultExtension: 'js' },
                'ng2-bs3-modal': { main: '/bundles/ng2-bs3-modal.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
                'ng2-smart-table': { main: 'bundles/table.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
                'ng2-completer': { main: 'ng2-completer.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
                'lodash': { main: 'lodash.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
                'file-saver': { format: 'global', main: 'FileSaver.js', defaultExtension: 'js'},
                'angular2-busy': { main: './index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
                'moment': { main: 'moment', defaultExtension: 'js' },            
                'ng2-toastr': { main: '/bundles/ng2-toastr.min.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },     
            }
      });
    })(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found one work around, I copied my node_modules folder from my project to the publish package and saw the error was gone